# Find a matrix with optimization

Tags: matlab, matrix, mathematical-optimization, sparse-matrix

In matlab, I have this objective function:

```
function answer = OBJ(alpha,D,y,lambda)
    answer = norm(D*alpha - y,2)^2 + lambda*norm(alpha,1);
end
```

without any constraint, I want to find `alpha`, in this function:

```
OBJ_F = @(x)OBJ(x,D,y,0.5);
```

what is the best optimization function for this work and how to do it?

**for example:** I defined an empty constraint `CON_F` and with `fmincon` function, I solve this problem, but this solution is slow, I want the best solution for this work

```
option = optimoptions(@fmincon, 'display','off','algorithm','interior-point');
[alpha,fval] = fmincon(OBJ_F,INIT,[],[],[],[],[],[],CON_F,option);
```

**NOTE:** D is 9*10000 --  y is 9*1 -- alpha is 10000*1

Answer (score 1):

Try Genetic Algorithm. It works with row vector and in your case `alpha` is a col vector. So you need to change the objective function a little;

```
function answer = OBJ(alpha,D,y,lambda)
alpha = alpha';
    answer = norm(D*alpha - y,2)^2 + lambda*norm(alpha,1);
end

OBJ_F = @(x)OBJ(x,D,y,0.5); 
problem.fitnessfcn  = OBJ_F;
problem.nvars = size(alpha,1);
problem.options = gaoptimset('display','off');
[alpha fval] = ga(problem);
alpha = alpha';
```

Comment: what were the issues ?